# Storing DOM snapshots and logs of Cypress in CI for debugging purpose

Tags: cypress

When using Cypress tests locally and in a CI pipeline. In the CI Pipeline some of them fail.

Cypress already allows to take screenshots and send them over to Cypress dashboard, but those seems to support only screenshots and videos.

Now when we run cypress locally using `npx cypress open` and run the test, we are able to go back and forth through all the states of the page and debug the failure, by inspecting the DOM and so on.

Is there any possibility to persist those DOM snapshots when Cypress is run in the CI and maybe load them later in the Cypress GUI or is this just wishful thinking?

Closest solution I found is https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/cyclope-intro/ but it does not seem to allow to go back in the history, like the Cypress GUI does.

Comment: This might also be helpful: https://github.com/NeuraLegion/cypress-har-generator - it generates HAR files which can show the network requests during a test (by drag'n'dropping the file into Chrome)

Answer (score 0):

The commercial product https://deploysentinel.com/ does exactly this.

For installation you need the NPM plugin `@deploysentinel/cypress-debugger/plugin` which records the DOM that can be later viewed on their dashboard.